# Redirect to view just before logging in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

How do i redirect someone who tries to login to another view to add a extra step to the authentication?

I tried this in the **AuthenticateUsers.php**

```
public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            //return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
            return redirect('/auth/'.Auth::id());
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
```

I'm trying to make it show the "/auth/" view just before logging in, and it does show the view but it still logs me in.

Comment: have you tried to remove Auth middleware from your route?

Comment: there is no Auth middleware in my route.

`Route::get('/auth/{id}', 'AuthController@index');`

Comment: can you show the route you want the user to first access?

Comment: `Route::get('/auth/{id}', 'AuthController@index');` this is the route i want people to go to after they pressed "login". It does work but i get logged in aswell, i just want the login to happen after the redirect to "/auth" and then have them put a randomized string in a input field (they get it from an email) then when they press authenticate they login

Comment: @lewis4u This is not the issue i'm having..

Answer (score 0):

You set your redirect just after `attemptLogin()`

```
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
    return redirect('/auth/'.Auth::id());
}
```

What this code says is that, "If the user successfully logs in, redirect them to '/auth/$id'. That's why you area always logged in when you get redirected.

Place your redirect just before that line

```
return redirect('/auth/'.Auth::id());
if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
    //do stuff
}
```

But now, you will never be able to log in, because you always return before you reach the login.

I suggest you go for manual authentication. You can find help here:
http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/221/manually-logging-a-user-in

http://tutsnare.com/authentication-with-laravel-5/

Comment: If i put the redirect before the attemptLogin, it will not redirect me when i press login in the first place, i want to be able to redirect a user when they click on login then show them an authentication form and then log them in after its correctly filled in

Comment: No you cannot do that. Once you pass `attempLogin()`, you are already connected. Sorry.

Comment: That's weird, there is no way to do this?

Comment: there is. I said so in my answer. You have to do manual authentication. I even gave you some links. But you could google for more

Comment: Ah, okay! thank you, i will try and figure this out haha

Comment: @MarioEekma I was doing something similar and ended up swapping out the ```attempt()``` call for a ```validate()``` call. This will check that the creds entered are correct and valid, but wont actually perform the login step (allowing you to add another step in there)